# Create file with PIC18 Microcontroller

Tags: c, microcontroller, pic

I am creating a data logger with a PIC18 microcontroller, and I'm writing the code in C.

I want to create a file containing all the data I've recorded. Inicially I'd like to create 2 file types. One of them .txt and the other one in .pqd (PQDIF format).

The problem with all this is that I can't find anywhere the structure fo a txt file. I've found a dll written in VB for pqd which can be translated to C, but it's difficult, so I've decided to start with the easier one.

Does anyone know where I can find the txt's logical structure. If so, do you know how I could look for other file types' structures?

Sorry for any english mistakes.

Comment: Text files don't have "logical structure".  They are literally just files contain text.

Comment: And what about the file length, size, font, etc?? Shouldn't they be part of a logical structure?

Comment: Text files don't contain font information; they are literally just text.

Comment: Well .... didn't know that. Thank you for helping. But could you tell me where I can find logical structures for files which actually have logical structure? I know PQD files have a logical and physical structure, which is kinda complicated.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no idea what a PQD file is.

Comment: Why don't you just want to write a text file? It's the easiest thing there is, just a long list of ascii characters, perfect for data logging. I don't know why you want to mess with fonts.

Comment: PQD is the format of PQDIF, which means, Power Quality Data Interchange Format. It's kinda tricky. If you have any interests you can search for PQDCom4.dll

Comment: @Tim Actually I didn't wanna mess with fonts. I just wanted something that could be read from a normal computer, and thought that it was necessary a format for a .txt file

Comment: Might be easier to save the data as CSV, then convert it to a PQDIF file on a PC.

Comment: For pretty much any format for which a definition is publicly available you need [Wotsit.org](http://www.wotsit.org/).  PQD not mentioned though, it is a bit obscure or at least domain specific.  It is intended for exchanging power quality data.  Unless your application is in this domain, it is probably inappropriate.

Comment: @Cliffor I know. But my data is in that domain. Thank you for your reply

Comment: Fair enough.  It was not clear to me that you were aware of that.  After all you seemed pretty unclear about what a text file was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no structure. Just use the Microchip Application Libraries and you're on your way:
http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=2680&dDocName=en547784

Here is the MDD section:
http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=2680&dDocName=en537999

What's more, they have existing demo applications for logging data from the analog-to-digital converter (ADC) to the text file on a regular basis. You can either purchase a $50 demo board to get up and running immediately, or you can order free sample PIC18 chips (chips and shipping are FREE), and build your own system on a solderless breadboard.
http://www.microchip.com/samples/

I have personally written SD card loggers to text/CSV files for PIC18, PIC24F, and PIC32mx chips on numerous occasions. You can find some of my examples if you look for posts by user "Dogbertius" on the Microchip.com forums.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Text files have a format only in the sense of encoding used ([ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii), [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf-8), [EBCDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ebcdic) etc.) and certainly in the case of ASCII there are [platform specific conventions for end-of-line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_of_line), which may variously be CR, CR+LF or LF for example.

A plain text file is just that - the C source code you are writing for this application is plain text for example, and you could load a plain text file into whatever editor you are using to edit code for example. The rendering of a plain-text file (font, text size, newline handling etc.) is not encoded in the file, it is entirely down to the application presenting the data (such as a text editor, or even the Windows/DOS "[type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_%28command%29)" command).

There are structured formats based on plain-text such as [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xml), [RTF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) and [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) for example.  Details of these can be found at [Wotsit.org](http://www.wotsit.org).  XML is good for complex data structures, RTF for formatted text and page presentation, and CSV for simple fixed format data records - especially numeric data.  Any spreadsheet application for example will read CSV directly, placing each "value" in a separate cell.  There are other text based [mark-up formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language) such as [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) or even the [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) format used by Stackoverflow.

The PIC18 is probably unsuited to building complex formats, you are better off perhaps passing simple raw data in a proprietary format and then processing that on a PC to transform it into whatever you need.